# How to keep archive table accessible for some users which is not frequently accessible?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning, olap, archive

I have partitioned my table based on some boundary ranges.

My Database is built at MSSQL server 2008 R2.

I have done partitioning for a table which has 40 million records in it. Now it's time to move some historical data from my production table into Archive table and I have planned to keep the historical data at my Archive table for some period of time (2 months) because unfortunately some clients may ask for the old data access. So, the production table will be frequently accessed by users where as the Archive table is going to be accessed less frequent.

Finally I got confused that how to keep both production table and Archive table accessible in an efficient manner ?

I have a OLAP database which fetches data from the Production table but after moving some data to Archive table, how can I manage that or how to retrieve from both the production and Archive table ?

Is there any good plan for my issue ?

Kindly advice me on that.